# Export using BCP as ASCII text

Tags: sql-server-2008, bcp

I have a script that stores data in a temporary table to be exported by running BCP using xp_cmdshell.

The trouble is that BCP insists on exporting the data in Unicode and I need it to be in ASCII.

I've tried using a format file but I don't think I have the correct type.

```
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-

instance">
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" />
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="line" xsi:type="SQLCHAR" />
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

What is the correct type to save the text as ASCII?

Comment: I think if you look at the -C parameter that would do it.  Not in the format file.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: What code page did you specify?

Comment: This is the command that I am sent to the command shell before I tried the format file `'bcp ##temp_file out "' + @filepath + '\tables\' + @curTable + '.sql" -T -c -C ACP -e "' + 
  @filepath + '\errors\tables\' + @curTable + '.txt"'`

Comment: Try -C 1252 instead of -C ACP I think it's the same thing but it might fix it.

Comment: I just tried it. No luck.

Comment: What is your normal codepage? (run chcp on the command prompt)

Comment: My normal codepage is 437.